# My Edit button in Bootstrap mvc modal popup is not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

My edit modal form is not showing when I click on edit button

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult UpStaffDetail()
{
    using (var db = new ASPNETMASTERPOSTEntities())
    {
        var dataList = db.tblCompanies.Include("tblStaffs").ToList();

        var modifiedData = dataList.AsEnumerable()
                                   .SelectMany(x => x.tblStaffs.Select(d => new StaffManagementModel
                                                                            {
                                                                                CompanyId = x.CompanyId,
                                                                                DateJoin = x.DateJoin,
                                                                                Department = x.Department,
                                                                                JobTitle = x.JobTitle,
                                                                                StaffId = d.StaffId,
                                                                                Picture = d.Picture,
                                                                                StaffNo = d.StaffNo,
                                                                                FName = d.FName,
                                                                                LName = d.LName,
                                                                                BirthDate = d.BirthDate,
                                                                                PhoneNo = d.PhoneNo,
                                                                                Email = d.Email,
                                                                                FirstName = d.FirstName,
                                                                                LastName = d.LastName,
                                                                                PhoneNumb = d.PhoneNumb
                                                                            })).FirstOrDefault();

        return Json(modifiedData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}

function upStaffDetails($StaffId)
{
    var tblStaffs = [];
    var company = new Object();

    var staff = new Object();

    $("#staffId").val($StaffId);

    if ($StaffId != 0)
    {
        jQuery.ajax({
               url: "@Url.Action("UpStaffDetail", "Home")" + "?StaffId=" + $StaffId + "&Department=abc",
               data:({
                   company: company
               }),
               type: "Get",
               dataType: "json",
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

               success: function (result) {
                   company: company
                   console.log(result);
                   if (result != null) {
                       $("#staffId").val(staff.StaffId);
                       $("#companyId").val(company.CompanyId);
                       $("#date").val(company.DateJoin);
                       $("#department").val(company.Department);
                       $("#jobTilte").val(company.JobTitle);
                       $("#image").val(staff.Picture);
                       $("#staffNo").val(staff.StaffNo);
                       $("#fName").val(staff.FName);
                       $("#lName").val(staff.LName);
                       $("#birthDate").val(staff.BirthDate);
                       $("#phone").val(staff.PhoneNo);
                       $("#email").val(staff.Email);
                       $("#firstName").val(staff.FirstName);
                       $("#lastName").val(staff.LastName);
                       $("#phonenumber").val(staff.PhoneNumb);

                       tblStaffs.push(staff);

                       company.tblStaffs = tblStaffs;
                   }
               }
        });
```